# i found an error during installing wordpress plugins shows error when specifically i installed woocommerce,yoast seo and ithems plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Installation failed: Could not copy file. better-wp-security/webpack.config.js

Comment: You should be more specific; Include the version of everything you mentioned, describe more about the environment, e.g. where is it installed? And list the  steps you have taken.

Answer (score 0):

its shows error because where my website is hosted the disk space is full because of that 
I found an error could not copy the file.